# How can I cancel exchange appointment when using on Exchange Web Service?

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2013

I am trying to use EWS to schedule an appointment then cancel it using EWS.I have 2 domains configured on my exchange server `old_domain.com` and `new_domain.com`.

`username@old_domain.com` is the fully qualified username and it is the one I must log in with to be authorized. The `new_domain.com` is set as an alias and is used as the default for everything. For example, when I send an email, by default it comes out of `username@new_domain.com` not `username@old_domain.com`

I was able to created the appointment with no issue. However, the Organizer is showing at `username@new_domain.com` not the fully quantified domain `username@old_domain.com`. So when I cancel the appointment, I get the following error

> User must be an organizer for CancelCalendarItem action.

Here is my code.

```
// create the service
WebCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "old_domain.com");
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
{
        Credentials = credentials,
        Url = new Uri("https://webmail.old_domain.com/ews/exchange.asmx"),
};


// create the appointment 
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service)
{
        Subject = "Test",
        Start = DateTime.Now,
        StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local,
        ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60,
};

appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddMinutes(60);
appointment.EndTimeZone = appointment.StartTimeZone;
appointment.Resources.Add("room1@old_domain.com");
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);


// cancel the meeting 
appointment.CancelMeeting();
```

How can I correctly cancel my appointment using EWS?

Comment: The domains don't really matter as the underlying EX address is more important. Are you trying to cancel the Organizer version of the appointment or the one that is stored in the resource (or other attendees) mailbox (this is what the error message is pointing too).

Comment: I would want to cancel the appointment for all. Cancel and send  email stating the appointment was cancelled

Answer (score 0):

I was able to created it by setting the organizer address after the appointment was created

```
// create the service
WebCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "password", "old_domain.com");
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013)
{
        Credentials = credentials,
        Url = new Uri("https://webmail.old_domain.com/ews/exchange.asmx"),
};

// create the appointment 
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service)
{
        Subject = "Test",
        Start = DateTime.Now,
        StartTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local,
        ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60,
};

appointment.End = appointment.Start.AddMinutes(60);
appointment.EndTimeZone = appointment.StartTimeZone;
appointment.Resources.Add("room1@old_domain.com");
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);

var appt = Appointment.Bind(service, appointment.Id,
                    new PropertySet(AppointmentSchema.Organizer)
                    );

appt .Organizer.Address = "username@old_domain.com";
appt.Update(WebService.ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```